# Query shows redundant ID's

Tags: php, mysql

I' am making a messaging system like Facebook has. I' am stuck where I have to Query the database and get the conversation between **User 1** and **User 2**.

**MySQL Query**

```
SELECT 
    messages.message_id, 
    messages.message_from, 
    messages.message_to
FROM 
    messages
INNER JOIN
    profiles
WHERE 
    messages.message_to = '1' AND messages.message_from = '2' OR
    messages.message_to = '2' AND messages.message_from = '1'
ORDER BY 
    messages.message_id 
DESC
```

**Database Structure and Query Result**

[image: Database Structure and Query Result]

**Database Scheme**

[image: Database Scheme]

As you can see, **message_id** has redundant ID's. There is something am not doing right in my Query, **What am I missing?**

Comment: I'm not a MySql guy, but it looks to me like your join is incomplete.

Comment: can you post your table schema ?

Comment: @JohnieKarr thanks for the head up, let me recheck what am I missing there.

Comment: Where is the schema of profile table ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

> SELECT DISTINCT messages.message_id